# Преобразование времени

Tags: время, java

Как можно из 4.46875 получить 4 дня 3 часа 45 минут?
Получаю ответ именно в таком виде, мне нужно преобразовать в количество дней, часов, минут...

Comment: Это из Excel'я что ли? Там время в таком формате хранится - посмотри на алгоритм @VladD ниже. Правда, 0.46 - никак не может соответствовать 3.45 часам...

Comment: @Gorets: вот ещё пример по теме: https://ideone.com/ki29ui

Comment: внимание правильный ответ: никак, т.к. мы можем только угадывать что означает каждая цифра. Хотя один вариант есть:

    if(input.equals("4.46875")) return "4 дня 3 часа 45 минут";

Comment: @jmu: если на то уж пошло, то просто `return "4 дня 3 часа 45 минут";`, про другие значения аргумента ничего не сказано[.](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, [так](http://ideone.com/5NibmZ):

```
double rawDays = 4.46875;
int days = (int)Math.floor(rawDays);
double rawRestHours = (rawDays - days) * 24;
int hours = (int)Math.floor(rawRestHours);
double rawRestMinutes = (rawRestHours - hours) * 60;
int minutes = (int)Math.floor(rawRestMinutes);
double restSeconds = (rawRestMinutes - minutes) * 60;
```

---

PS: В Java 8 будет тип данных, представляющий период времени.

Comment: ты серьёзно? такой способ в джаве?

Comment: @Gorets: есть вариант лучше? (не используя Joda Time)

Comment: конечно, можно засетить это значение в Calendar и дальше брать с него все что надо (дни, секунды, часы, минуты)

Comment: @Gorets: Не, так неправильно. `Calendar` представляет _момент_ времени, а не _период_. Поэтому могут возникать приколы, например, при переходе на летнее время или там в високосные годы. (Если наш период времени имеет длину в несколько лет.)

Comment: @VladD `floor(0.46875*24)=11` часов - как то не вытанцовывается...

Comment: @Barmaley: почему не вытанцовывается? 4,46 дня — это чуть меньше, чем 4 с половиной дней, полдня — это как раз 12 часов.

Comment: ребят спасибо всем большое, но мне оказывается нужно было вывести всего лишь количество дней) прекращайте спор)

Comment: @VladD - ну правильно, а у автора ~4 часа, но никак не 11...

Comment: @Barmaley: Ставлю на ошибку во входных данных :-)

Comment: @Barmaley, по ссылке же есть результат компиляции http://ideone.com/5NibmZ

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(String.format(
    "%1$te дня %1$tH час(а/ов) %1$tM минут(а/ы)",
    new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        (int) (4.46875 * 24 * 3600))));
```

Comment: Неправильно: https://ideone.com/1qpXP4